# loop from (sheet.name) to (sheet.name)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

how to loop through sheets, from (sheet.name) to ( sheet.name) and find(TextBox1.Value) , then Delete Entire Row that contain the (TextBox1.Value)

- the from (sheet.name) = TextBox2.Value
- the to ( sheet.name) = Textbox3.Value

I am not very good with coding but I try . so any help will be appreciated
i do searching and found nothing can help me

and here is my last try of cod

```
Private Sub cmdega_Click()
Dim shArr, j As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fromsheet As String
Dim tosheet As String
Dim id As String

fromsheet = Textbox2.Value
tosheet = TextBox3.Value
id = TextBox1.Value

shArr = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31")



For j = LBound(Array("fromsheet")) To UBound(Array("tosheet"))

    With Sheets(shArr(j))
         .Cells.Find(What:=id, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
              xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
       .Rows.EntireRow.Select
       .Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
    
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by _from (sheet.name) to ( sheet.name)_ , is that all the sheets ? What are the sheet names like, are they Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 etc ?

Comment: my sheets name is ( "1") ,("2"),...... until ("31") , The number of days of the month. each sheet contain names and id numbers . What I am trying to do is to specify specific days,( let's say from day 4 to day 11)  which I specify by a textbox2 that specifies the beginning and a textbox3 that specifies the end of the required days. Thus, searching for an ID number i specify in (textbox1)  and lookup the row that contains the ID number then delete the entire row

Comment: Is the ID in a specific column or could it be anywhere on the sheet ? Can the ID appear more than once on the same row ?

Comment: it's in the column A . the ID Will appear once on the same row . and appear 2 time in the column ..  ( always under each other )

Comment: Ok I have simplified my answer.

Comment: This looks so dangerous: imagine you have 4 sheets, from "Sheet1" to "Sheet4" and you put "Sheet3" in front of the others in order to protect it from deletion. It will be deleted anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdega_Click()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngFound As Range, rngDelete As Range
    Dim fromsheet As String, tosheet As String
    Dim id As String, firstAddr As String, n As Long
    
    fromsheet = Textbox2.Value
    tosheet = TextBox3.Value
    id = "ID" 'TextBox1.Value
    
    ' check valid input
    If Not (IsNumeric(fromsheet) And IsNumeric(tosheet)) Then
        MsgBox "To or From numeric", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' loop through sheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
        ' only numeric sheet names
        If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
            
            Set rngDelete = Nothing
            Select Case CLng(ws.Name)
                Case CLng(fromsheet) To CLng(tosheet) ' range from to
                    
                    ' search
                    Set rngFound = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=id, after:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    
                    ' was a row found
                    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                        ' nothing found
                    Else
                        firstAddr = rngFound.Address
                        Do
                            
                            ' Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.CodeName, rngFound.Address
                            ' build delete range
                            If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                                Set rngDelete = rngFound
                            Else
                                Set rngDelete = Application.Union(rngFound, rngDelete)
                            End If
                            n = n + 1
                            Set rngFound = ws.Range("A:A").FindNext(rngFound)
                        Loop While rngFound.Address <> firstAddr ' continue search
                        
                    End If
            End Select
            
            ' delete rows in one operation
            If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                With rngDelete
                    '.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    .EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
      
    MsgBox n & " rows matching '" & id & "' deleted", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Everything is fine, except one issue.. sheets(5,6,9) only , the TextBox1.value not deleted from them when founded. Unless you specify the same sheet name ( 5 or 6 or 9 )in the input field(TextBox2 or TextBox3)

Comment: @ahmed Try updated code, I have cast the relevant variables from strings to integer (long) .

Comment: You did it again. Your magic touch saved me . now every thing is work perfectly .. thanks again and to the last of my life :**

Comment: @ahmed Sorry my mistake, with string variables comparison `Case "1" To "2"` would select "1","2","10","11" etc to "19". "4" to "9" works but "4" to "11" wouldn't because the first character of 11 is less than the first character of 4.